# XML finding namespace inside namespace

Tags: xml, namespaces

I have this code :

```
<st:friend xmlns:st='areacode:819'>
<st:name xmlns:st='urn:555'>Company</st:name>
<type>B</type>
</st:friend>
```

Can someone explain me why st is declared twice?

Comment: Thanks, (Yes I forgot the </sr:friend> at the end. But it's exactly what I was looking for, to understand, the urn:555 goes to ! <br> thanks again @Bruno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML example isn't well formed as it does not close the `<st:friend>` element but I'll assume that you meant to close it after the `<type>` element.

What is going on here is that the `<st:name>` element is redefining what namespace the `st` prefix refers to (to `urn:555`). This definition applies to the `<st:name>` element only (and would apply to child elements too if there were any). Once you are past the closing tag `<st:name/>`, the `st` prefix refers again to its original namespace (`areacode:819`).